# convert a cck field from integer to string (text)

Tags: 7, entities, database

How do I convert an existing integer field to text without having to copy paste manualy each value on each node and then delete the old integer field
I´m using Drupal 7.9

I tried altering the database.. on the definition of the field and the value type
I'm still getting errors

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_ubi_gps_x_format en field_sql_storage_field_storage_load() (línea 360 de /modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).

Notice: Undefined variable: regexp en number_field_widget_validate() (línea 389 de /modules/field/modules/number/number.module).
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Empty regular expression en number_field_widget_validate() (línea 389 de /modules/field/modules/number/number.module)
```

that is because the validation and presentation of the field has remained as integer..
I can't find in the DB where it stores that to copy if from another text field

I've so far altered field_data_field_FIELDNAME_THAT_WAS_INT changing field_FIELDNAME_value
from int to varchar and paradores_field_config . copying the blob data field from a text to ID of the FIELDNAME and using text on type and module fields

Comment: finally I've done it by creating another content with a text type and imorted all data from the table field_data_field_FIELDNAME_THAT_IS_INT to field_data_field_FIELDNAME_THAT_IS_TEXT ..empty the cache and voilla, all works.. then deleted the old one

Answer (score -1):

You would have to change the type in field data and field revision tables and add the FIELD_NAME_format column in both the tables.
Change the type and module columns in field_config to 'text'. And change the data column in field_config and field_config_instance tables.

For more info on this you can visit this [link](http://www.innoraft.com/node/40).